# Problems with the date object

Tags: javascript

I'm taking the strings entered, converting them to ints (as I think I need), grabbing the first three characters of the month value, lowercasing it, and then dividing it by three to define which month it is.
Now the part thats confusing me is the Date object. I think that I'm doing it right, I input everything but it only sends prompts for the first few variables and doesn't give me an alert box showing me what info is stored in d.

```
var birthYear = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your birth year:'));
var birthMonth = prompt ('Enter the name of the month of birth:');
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
var milliDay = 1000*60*60*24; //Milliseconds in a day
monthAbb = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
chineseZod = 12;
zodCycle = 1924; //Chinese Zodiac Cycle
var monthArr = new Array(11);


monthArr [0] = "jan";
monthArr [1] = "feb";
monthArr [2] = "mar";
monthArr [3] = "apr";
monthArr [4] = "may";
monthArr [5] = "jun";
monthArr [6] = "jul";
monthArr [7] = "aug";
monthArr [8] = "sep";
monthArr [9] = "oct";
monthArr [10] = "nov";
monthArr [11] = "dec";

var monthNum = monthAbb.indexOf(birthMonth.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase()) / 3;
alert(monthNum);
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDate);
alert(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the following line:

```
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDate);
```

`birthDate` is `undefined`. I think you meant `birthDay`, as that's what you use earlier:

```
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
```

This sort of thing is usually very easy to work out if you just check the browser console... Here's a screenshot of what I saw as soon as I tried your code on http://jsfiddle.net in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Staring at code for 3 hours breaks my eyes apparently, haha. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make! Glad I could help :)